# SQLite Database in external Micro Sdcard

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to know.

I have one external micro sd card in my tab.

I want to create a SQLite database inside my Micro sd card .

```
public static final String  DATABASE_FILE_PATH = "/extSdCard";
```

I am giving my path of external micro sd card but error showing.

```
Unable to open Database
```

Is it possible to create Database in external Memory card?

update:-

```
public static final String  DATABASE_FILE_PATH = "/extSdCard";
    public static final String  DATABASE_NAME = "mytest";

public SDcardDatabase(final Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_FILE_PATH +  DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }
```

Comment: have u Add    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> this permissison in manifest

Comment: no answer for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create database in external sdcard by this given path.

```
"/mnt/externalSDcard/dbname"
```

for detail check this:-

[SQLite Database in Samsung Tab2 (External Micro sd card)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727006/sqlite-database-in-samsung-tab2-external-micro-sd-card/14744166#14744166)

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33182/why-is-the-sd-card-mounted-to-sdcard-external-sd-instead-of-sdcard-or-m