# SQLite Database in Samsung Tab2 (External Micro sd card)

Tags: android, sqlite

These are memory in my SAMSUNG TAB2.

1-`Internal`

2-`Sdcard`

3-**`**Extrenal_sdcard**`**(Removable memory) don't be confuse between `sdcard` and `Extrenal_sdcard`.

`Extrenal_sdcard` is `micro sd card` which we can remove from tab.

I was trying to create SQLite Database inside the **Extrenal_sdcard**(Removable).

But i didn't got success.

I was trying to do like what we do in `Sdcard`.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState() +filename
```

but for **Extrenal_sdcard**(Removable) it was not working.

**is it possible what i am trying to do or NOT.**

please assist me.

Do not provide the link related How to create database in sdcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

WE need to provide this  path for **External Micro Sd card.**

```
"/mnt/name_of_your_card/your_dbfile"
```

example:-

```
"/mnt/MyExternal_Card/My_database"
```

Thanks to this link.

[How can I get external SD card path for Android 4.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0)